# Safe Delete/Update mode with DataGrip

Tags: mysql, workbench, datagrip

I was wondering if there is a Safe Delete/Update setting for Datagrip, just like Workbench. I tried to look in the documentation, online forums, etc... and could not find anything.

Thanks!

Comment: What is Safe delete/update? Can you describe the functionality of it in Workbench?

Comment: Basically you cannot do an Update/delete without a key in where clause:
"Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect."

Comment: Got it. There is no such possibility now in DataGrip. Please, share your thoughts here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-1456

Answer (score 3):

In DataGrip 2018.3 there will be a setting you need. It will prevent you from running these queries and also show you the warning beforehand.

[image]